# Pass a shared data structure to an Android Activity without Serialization/Intent

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a ListView that is displaying data from a large dataset. The data is retrieved from the web and put into a `List<Data>` (i.e. in memory) by a background task. (Think email inbox with polling updates.)

My problem is how to pass that data to the ListFragment/ListView/ListAdapter to display.

This List isn't permanent (so not in a Content Provider) but lives longer than activity (it's updated in the background when the activity isn't alive yet).

The only options appears to be:

1. Pass it via an Intent/Bundle. This requires serialization on some level which will be very expensive for my long list, especially as each time the List updated in the background, I have to set a new List which means the entire list gets re-serialized.
2. Create a Singleton that provides the list from anywhere in the program, and access SingletonListProvider.getInstance().getList() from my ListAdaptor. I don't like singletons and I'm worried about concurrency.
3. Use a ContentProvider. Seems overkill for a simple List<> that currently lives in memory

Are there any other options?

It seems I have little control over how the Activity (ListFragment in this case) is created so I can't just pass the List as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use Database, especially if your data-structure large.
By the way, you shouldn't create `ContentProvider` enough to extend `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_sqliteopenhelper

Comment: Seems a lot of overhead for a simple ArrayList. Is there really no way for an Activity to see data held by other objects?

Comment: You can use singletone as data provider. But for android it's not a common prectice.